# Creating a text file based on the current value of a variable, creates a text file with its content as the previous value of that same variable

Tags: batch-file

The code is as follows,

```
@echo off 
if not exist c:\Locker (
    cd/
    md Locker
    cd windows\system32
    echo Set the password for your locker:-
    set /p pass=
    echo %pass%>text.txt
) else (
    echo Folder is created
)
```

Here, suppose of I set pass = 12345, the text file does not hold any such value
If once again I run my program and set pass=abcde, then the text file shows the value 
as "1234".
Kindly give me the reason behind this and what to do to avoid this??
Thanks in advance.........

Comment: what is the `/p` supposed to do in your `set`?

Comment: @zshooter The `/p` prompts for input.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You pass 12345 as the password, it writes it to text file, then you give it abcde, which it overwrites the old one with, whats the problem?

Comment: No, when i pass 12345 it doesnt write to the file, but if i write abcde then it writes 12345, similiarly now if i try to write qwerty then value written in the file is abcde.

Answer (score 1):

you need SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION as you are using a [variable set in parentheses context](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1460) :

```
@echo off 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if not exist c:\Locker (
    cd/
    md Locker
    cd windows\system32
    echo Set the password for your locker:-
    set /p pass=
    echo !pass!>text.txt
) else (
    echo Folder is created
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: your code worked great, but it seems like since i have executed your code my machine has stopped taking input i.e. set /p pass= is just not working anymore in any of the batch files. So has it anything to do with "SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION" or anything else.......

Comment: No. Setlocal does not affect the `set /p` .But if your batch is not run as administrator you'll be not able to create file in system32 dir.

Comment: yea I was running it as an administrator.......              but as soon as I reopened the CMD everything worked great............ thanks, I have created a small app b'coz of you :)